# How to debug a manually configured ReactJs Project in vscode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code, webpack

For the sake of learning i configured webpack and babel manually in my ReactJS project and at a moment i needed to debug my code so i created my `launch.json` file (see below)
and set up breakpoint, the debugger actually starts and lunches the local server instance in chrome but my breakpoints are ignored. and therefor i though the problem was in my config falsely and tried to resolve it, however after a while i created a dummy project using `create-react-app` and run the debugger thereafter and it hits the breakpoints surely, so i'm sure now it's a setup problem, most likely I'am missing some packages which comes with create-react-app that's needed to run the debugger properly, is this actually the problem and if it's what are those dependencies ?

This is my launch.json file:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:9500/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my manually configured webpack:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports =  {
    entry: "./index.js",
    mode: "development",
    output : {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/dist"),
        filename: "main.js",
    },
    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: "./public/index.html"})],
    target: "web",
    devServer: {
        port: "9500",
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, "./public"),
        },
        open: true,
        hot: true, 
        liveReload: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
        ],
    }
}
```

and this is the config babel:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed `react-scripts` package in my project and add the commands to my `package.json`, as `react-scripts start` instead of manually starting the webpack dev server `webpack-dev-server .` and  the debugger actually hits my break-points.